# Fetching all collections in Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firestore in my project, so i want to show all collection names in my project.

Is it posible to get all collection names from Firebase project.

Thanks..

Comment: Python code solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76017187/13676217

Answer (score 28):

There are limited public APIs to get a list of top-level collections.  Mobile clients (Android, iOS, web) have no API.  Node.js admin clients have [listCollections()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Firestore.html#listCollections) on [Firestore](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Firestore.html) to get that list.  Or, if you're looking for subcollections nested under a document, use [DocumentReference.listCollections()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html#listCollections).

If you want to get a list of anything using any client SDK, you should prefer to maintain that list yourself in a known document in a known collection.

A database model that depends on client knowing how many subcollection exists is not a very good model for Firestore.  Firestore has two ways of storing varible-sized lists of things:

1. Array fields in a document (for limited sizes)
2. Documents within a collection (for highly scalable sizes)

Comment: Thank you Doug Stevenson, actually getCollections() is using for subcollections but i am looking for collections list and also its not support in web.

Comment: The method I linked to is a method on Firestore, and it will get you all top-level collections (not subcollections of a document).  But, as I said, no such operation is supported for mobile clients.

Comment: `getCollections()` has been replaced with `listCollections()`

Comment: @LahiruChandima Looking at the API docs, it seems they both still exist with the same documentation.

Answer (score 22):

You can do the following:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const db = admin.firestore();

db.listCollections()
  .then(snapshot=>{
      snapshot.forEach(snaps => {
        console.log(snaps["_queryOptions"].collectionId); // LIST OF ALL COLLECTIONS
      })
  })
  .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

This works with NodeJS.
Remember that you will need to download `firebase-admin` and do the necessary configuration for Firebase server side.

Answer (score 11):

You can make a separate collection(say `listOfCollections`) which contains all the other collection names as documents or in an array of strings in one document as an alternative.

Then, whenever you are adding a new collection first add its name to the `listOfCollections`.

Comment: excellent workaround

Comment: working for me, I'm interesting what @DougStevenson think about this solution