# Fetching all collections in angular Firestore?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I want to get all collection names in my project.
Is it posible to get all collection names from angular Firebase project.

I saw this question and it not provide answer for angular firestore.
[Fetching all collections in Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48258632/9006622)

so this is not a duplicate question. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the SO question/answer you refer to in your question ([Fetching all collections in Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48258632/fetching-all-collections-in-firestore)) there is no client API (Android, iOS, web) to list collections (top collections or sub-collections).

Since, if I am not mistaking, with angular (and angularfire2) you are building a "client" app (that use the web API under the hood) you will not find any API for that.

You may maintain a list of collections in specific Firestore document(s), i.e. when you create a collection programmatically you update this list.