# Is there a way to get the name of a firestore Collection?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get the names of all collections in my firebase project but I have not seen a way to do so.
Even a simple console.log(collectionIdName) I have not been able to do.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48258632/fetching-all-collections-in-firestore

Comment: The answer of the duplicate will show you how to do that with a Cloud Function. This approach is inspired from the following [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-list-all-subcollections-of-a-cloud-firestore-document-17f2bb80a166), which describes how to list all subcollections of a Cloud Firestore document with the JS SDK. (Disclaimer: I'm the author)