# How can i fetch all collections stored in firestore using flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

[image: Image from cloud firestore showing all collections]

I want to fetch all collections made or stored in firestore using flutter. how can I do that?
I don't want to specify a collection reference. I want to see all collections I have in firebase.
how can I do that?

Please see the image. how can I fetch highlighted items in the flutter app?

thank you very much I am new to flutter. and this is my first Reddit question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fetching all collections in Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48258632/fetching-all-collections-in-firestore)

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible to do using the Flutter, Android, or iOS SDKs.

If you're trying to model a system where the user creates collections, it would be a much better idea to create a collection for user-generated data, and then create a document with a subcollection to store that data;

If you really need that functionality, firebase admin SDK may be able to help you out though.

```
const admin =  require(firebase-admin);
const db = admin.firestore();

db.listCollections()
.then(snapshot=>{
    snapshot.forEach(snaps=>{
        console.log(snaps["_queryOptions"].collectionId); 
    })
})
```

You can create a cloud function to return this data via an HTTP request.