# Get all collections name from firebase database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I want to know all collections name of the firebase database using js but still not get any solution.

I tried

```
db.collection().get().then(()=>{})
```

but it gives me an error, must write the collection name in collection

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fetching all collections in Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48258632/fetching-all-collections-in-firestore)

Comment: You may be interested by the following [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-list-all-subcollections-of-a-cloud-firestore-document-17f2bb80a166) which present a solution to list all subcollections of a Cloud Firestore document or list all the root collections of a Cloud Firestore database.

Answer (score 2):

Admin API will let you do that

```
const admin =  require(firebase-admin);
const db = admin.firestore();

db.listCollections()
...
```

see this thread for more details :
[Fetching all collections in Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48258632/fetching-all-collections-in-firestore)