# Firestore - get collection Entries from document in collection

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to get the value which is red marked in the Screenshot below.

I tried a lot things also with google, but I do not came to a good result.

My code so far:

```
firestore.collection('chats').doc(this.uid).get().subscribe(data => {
      alert(data.data());
    });
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What is the thing you circled in red? A collection? A document? Or something else? Note that collections should typically have known names, as you can't get "all subcollections" of a document, you'll need to know the name  of the collection already. Once you do, accessing it is `firestore.collection('chats').doc(this.uid).collection("the subcollection name").get()`

Comment: Hmm and what can I do if I never know the name ? Ist a genereated string. How can I change my structure to solve the problem? :/

Comment: Maybe we can solve this in that way: I make a request for the doc: firestore.collection('chats').doc(this.uid).what here to get it? and then I should get the document where I can make a IF for the this.uid and when matching then there should also be delivered the collection or do I understand it not right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you circled in red is a collection, you will have to *know* the collection name, as you can't [get "all subcollections" of a document(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48258632/fetching-all-collections-in-firestore/48258777#48258777) in the client-side SDKs.

So you'll need to know the name  of the collection already. Once you do, accessing it is:

```
firestore
  .collection('chats')
  .doc(this.uid)
  .collection("the subcollection name")
  .get()
```

Comment: Can I do it like this shema?

from beginning: chats will be a doc, than a collection with this.uid and then again a doc, is this possible? If yes, can you maybe send me a example how to do this? :) Thanks!

Comment: No. Firestore's data model is a pretty rigid sequence: the root consists of collections. Each collection contains document. And each document can contain collections again. If you want to generate IDs under a document, those IDs typically have a meaning. Create a collection with that name, for example `messages` if you're storing the messages for their chats, or `friends` if you're storing their friends for the chat. Even if you have just a single subcollection, give it a known name and use that in your code.

Comment: Thank you for explanation! 
One last question: I redesigned my structure so it should work but I do not know how to push an array, in that way, that the existing array entries stay here and only add one more entry in what array. I tried it this way:



`this.afStore.collection('users').doc(this.uid).get().subscribe(userData => {
      userData.data()['openChats'].forEach(chatUid => {
        alert(chatUid)
      });
    
      userData.ref.set({
        openChats: Array.of(this.o_uid)
      }, {merge:true})
    
    });`

Comment: That seems like a new problem, but you might want to have a look here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array