# Reading data from Cloud Firestore with Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

[image: Cloud Firestore]

Hello, Im building an app, and I would like to be able to show the collections outlined in the photo, these are the first collections, before any document, or field.

How do I write the reference to listview the 2 references? Like FirebaseFirestore.instance...?

[[image: Screenshot]]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

To get `x` collection from firestore, you need to use

```dart
final result = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("x").get();
```

It will provide a QuerySnapShot. More about [get-data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data)

Comment: you will also have doc after collection, start digging in, you will call `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("x").doc('y').get()`

Comment: Ok I see, I think my question was not clear enough. I wish to display the collections in a list, with this reference I will be entering the collection specified, but what I want is to display them only.

Comment: I have two main collections named cond_auto and examinadores, if I use FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("x").get() I will be forcing to enter into the specified ref. But I want to list them

Comment: You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48258777/10157127) for your case, I will prefer creating sub-collection or you can do two queries here