# How to list all non existent documents in a collection?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Say I have the following structure:
`collectionA/documentA/collectionB/documentB`
But I have set documentB directly to the above path (without explicitly creating collectionA, documentA or collectionB), so the document "documentA" is a non existent document that does not show in queries if I list all documents of collectionA even with admin sdk.
However the firebase web console somehow manages to list such documents. Not only that, I have also seen a third party app Firefoo list such documents and somehow even paginate the results. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this can be achieved with the
[Firestore REST API v1](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/listDocuments)
using the listDocuments endpoint and setting query param `showMissing` to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

All Firestore queries are based on having some data about that document present in the index that is used for the query. There is no public API to show non-existing documents.

The  Firebase console shows these documents based on [getting a list of all collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48258632/fetching-all-collections-in-firestore), and then building a data model from that.

Comment: Thanks for the response Frank, but I don't think its possible to infer document IDs by building a data model of existing data, as it turns out the "listDocuments()" endpoint in the REST API shows all documents including non existent ones