# Get list of all root level collections of Firebase Firestore in .Net

Tags: c#, firebase, .net-core, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get all the root-level collections of a Firebase Firestore Database in my server using .Net. I have tried Firebase Admin SDK but couldn't find the right method to get the list of collections. I also tried to find the rest API doing this but wasn't successful there either. So any way to get the list of the collections inside a Firebase Firestore would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For .NET, use [FirestoreDb.ListRootCollectionsAsync()](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.Firestore/latest/Google.Cloud.Firestore.FirestoreDb#Google_Cloud_Firestore_FirestoreDb_ListRootCollectionsAsync).

For REST, use [listCollectionIds](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.databases.documents/listCollectionIds).

See also:

- [Fetching all collections in Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48258632/fetching-all-collections-in-firestore)

Generally speaking, you should only use predictable collection names that you can hard code into your app, or store in other documents with known paths.  Collection names should not be based on variable data.  If your app needs to list collection names, it might not be very well structured.

Comment: The rest api gets the subCollections of a document. Is there any way to get root-level collections with rest api?